# pdftk issue after updating Ubuntu from 9.04 to 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, pdftk

We upgraded our server to 9.10 from 9.04 the other day, and it all went well except for one rather important program.

We're using pdftk to automatically generate filled out pdf forms. On 9.04, it worked just fine.
After updating to 9.10, the pdf forms would no longer be filled out - they'd just be empty.

I discovered that if I try to create an fdf file via pdftk from my PDF form, it just creates an empty fdf with no fields.

On windows, pdftk generates the fdf file just fine.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdftk/+bug/487922/comments/3

Package

```
libgcj10
```

so I removed it

```
sudo apt-get remove libgcj10
```

which also removed most all the other stuff for PDFTK

```
sudo apt-get install libgcj9-0
```

Said I needed to install all this other stuff, so I did that and ran

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install libgcj9-0
```

And then installed a older version of PDFTK from here

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/i386/pdftk/1.41-3ubuntu1

Then manually installed PDFTK

```
sudo dpkg -i pdftk_1.41-3ubuntu1_i386.deb
```